# How can I position my div next to the some text?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Using Bootstrap3, I'm trying to position my div beside some text.

**CODE:**

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block">
  <div style="width: 40px; position: absolute">
    <div style="padding-top: 100%;overflow: hidden; background-color: darkblue;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 30px; position: absolute">
    <div style="padding-top: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #f8ff15;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddORed

I just want to use this div like a span icon.

So moreover, I wonder how to make my div's height be responsive to the height of text or text typhograpy .

How to do it?

Comment: you cant use h tag inside p tag

Comment: There might be different solutions to this. But totally unrelated to the answer. Why not change the div to an image and use it as a pseudo? h1:before {} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put that DIV - but better as a SPAN - (which you already correctly defined as an `inline-block`) INTO the `h1` tag (BTW: no `h1` inside `p`!) and add `vertical-align:top;`, so it aligns with the upper border of the text line:

```html
<h1>Text
  <span style="position: relative; display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
    <div style="width: 40px; position: absolute">
      <div style="padding-top: 100%;overflow: hidden; background-color: darkblue;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 30px; position: absolute">
      <div style="padding-top: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #f8ff15;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</h1>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvVogM

Comment: Element div not allowed as child of element h1 in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you want to do by you can do this by using linear-gradient as background and no need to use all this markup:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to right, #f8ff15, #f8ff15) calc(100% - 10px) 0/ 30px calc(100% - 10px) no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkblue) 100% 0/ 40px 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Text</h1>
<br>
<h1>another<br> text</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just move your divs before you text and set the position to absolute.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MQboRj

```html
<div style="position: absolute; display: inline-block">
  <div style="width: 40px; position: absolute">
    <div style="padding-top: 100%;overflow: hidden; background-color: darkblue;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 30px; position: absolute">
    <div style="padding-top: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #f8ff15;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div><h1 style="padding-left:50px;">Here is what I want to position my blue and yellow square. And also I hope my square's height be equal to Text's height</h1></div>
```